# How to change CSS of popover for just one element?

Tags: bootstrap-4, popover

How to style specific Bootstrap popovers?

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap v4.0 and can successfully create a style for all popovers via CSS. However, I cannot find a way to style specific buttons, nor to dynamically change the styling via JS.

I'm looking to change the popover/tooltip's font size depending on conditions which vary. What's most important is dynamically changing the font-size (I can live with a global change, though only changing certain button's popovers would be ideal).

Example: This fails...
    alert( $('.popover-body').css('font-size') )

It just returns "undefined", even though the CSS is:

```
.popover-body {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    }
```

and the popovers respond appropriately to this font-size.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is hierarchical; you would need to work up the chain. Assuming you have two poovers, `#one` and `#two`, you could target `#one .popover-body` to exclusively target the first popover-body with CSS.

`alert($('.popover-body').css('font-size'))` fails because `$('.popover-body')` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection of elements. You'll either need to loop over them (with something like [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)), or target them individually by index with `$('.popover-body')[0].css('font-size'))`, for example.

Comment: $('.popover-header')[0] is returning undefined

Comment: JSON.stringify($('.popover-header')) returns {"length":0,"prevObject":{"0":{"location":{"href":"","ancestorOrigins":{},"origin":"file://","protocol":"file:","host":"","hostname":"","port":"","pathname":"","search":"","hash":""}},"context":{"location":{"href":"","ancestorOrigins":{},"origin":"file://","protocol":"file:","host":"","hostname":"","port":"","pathname":"","search":"","hash":""}},"length":1},"context":{"location":{"href":"","ancestorOrigins":{},"origin":"file://","protocol":"file:","host":"","hostname":"","port":"","pathname":"","search":"","hash":""}},"selector":".popover-header"}